# как обработать sql exception если все колонки пустые

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Как оптимизировать ниже запрос?

```
begin  
   select t1.status, t1.curr, t1.amount, t1.serv  
     into stat,curr,amnt,serv  
   from table1 t1  
   where t1.id = 78;   
exception when no_data_found then 
                  result := 1;  
                  stat := 'R';  
          when stat is null and curr is null and amnt is null and serv is null then  
                  result := 1;  
                  stat := 'R';   
end;
```

Выборка возвращает не no_data_found а пустые поля то есть null
Нужно чтобы по данному блоку падал в no_data_found если все столбцы будут равны null
Добавил это блок:

```
when stat is null and curr is null and amnt is null and serv is null then  
                      result := 1;  
                      stat := 'R';
```

Comment: Так  что у вас не получается?  Незаполненые колонки заполнить значениями по умолчанию? Вроде это же на уровне  ДМ делается: `stat char(1) not null default 'R'`.

Comment: Связаный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62858435

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему предварительно не проверить по типу if exists then exception?

В этом варианте вы сможете проверить ваши поля на null.

```
if exists ( select * from table1 where "condition") begin exception ... end
```

... спокойной вставляете данные

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/497257)

Comment: Является... @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica

Comment: Да после запроса можно проверить if stat is null and curr is null итд then raise exp end if; потом в exception    when no_data_found or my_exc then

Answer (score 2):

Просто включите условие для пустых колонок в  выборку:

```
create table t1 (id number, stat char (1), curr int, amnt int, serv int);
insert into t1 (id) values (78); 

var rc refcursor
declare rec t1%rowtype; result int;
begin 
    begin  
        select * into rec  
        from t1  
        where t1.id = 78 
        and not (stat is null and curr is null and amnt is null and serv is null);   
    exception when no_data_found then 
        result := 1;  
        rec.stat := 'R';
    end;
    open :rc for select result result, rec.stat stat from dual;  
end;
/

    RESULT STAT                            
---------- --------------------------------
         1 R
```